# how to add common variable for laravel and pass this data to all view all views

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a global variable and pass this into all view, so I can get this variable into all blade template

basically, my need is to pass my general setting controller value into my common blade view like header.blade.php

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Laravel documentation you can use view composer:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers

for using this feature in app > AppServiceProvider and in boot method you can use this approach for passing parameter to specific view If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered. this approach meet your need perfectly. for example you want to pass a parameter named `userName` to header.

```
View()->composer('header', function ($view){
    $userName= "username"    
    $view->with(['userName'=>$userName]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For that you will need to add some code in the App->Providers->AppServiceProvider.php like this:

```
public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*',function($view){

            $settings = Settings::firstOrNew(['id' => '1']); 
            $view->with('settings', $settings );
           
        });
    }
```

Comment: May be its help you to store data in common variable because boot Run first and store data in variable and after that you just have to pass the data in to your views like above @pixlogix show the code if this is not work post comments I will help you but I think Ik no it's work fine because this is correct way to do this